# PCR: From transgene/microgram to cell concentration

Tags: immunology, theoretical-biology, pcr, experimental-design, units

I am doing research on CAR T-cell kinetics. The measurement of CAR T-cell concentrations across time is normally carried out with qPCR (see [here](https://doi.org/10.1158/1078-0432.CCR-18-0758), Fig. 1). These concentrations are generally reported as transgene per microgram of DNA. My question is how to go from this number to a cell count estimate, for example cell per microliter of blood, which is sometimes reported (see [here](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa1707447), Fig. 3).

I understand this should be done with three conversion factors:

transgene/microgram * microgram/cell * cell/microliter * CAR cell/transgene = CAR cell/ microliter

I don't think the first two factors are hard to obtain, but I don't know about the third. I don't even know if this is right at all. Is there a straightforward or standard way to make this conversion?

From the first paper:

> A TaqMan-based qPCR assay was used for the detection of
> tisagenlecleucel transgene DNA (transgene copies/μg of DNA) in
> peripheral blood and bone marrow samples, with a lower limit of
> quantitation of 50 copies/μg of genomic DNA requiring 200 ng
> DNA/reaction. The assay tolerates ±10% variation in DNA input.

Comment: Please clarify your question by elaborating that qPCR-method directly in your question. Readers aren't motivated to look up that method from a complicated research paper. For example, I ask myself if "transgene" means how much 'CAR-DNA' was found within a sample tissue?

Comment: I hope that can be of help.